# Getting carrier's name with CoreTelephony returns just "Carrier"

Tags: iphone, core-telephony, carrier

I tried getting carrier name with this code (using CoreTelephony):

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netinfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSLog(@"Carrier Name: %@", [carrier carrierName]);
```

It returns "Carrier". If i go to iPhone settings my carrier's name is correct there. My iOS on the phone is v4.2.1.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am also facing same issue..did u fix the issue? @DixieFlatline

Comment: Does this Apple review safe?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really get string "Carrier" or **is the string empty**? Documentation says:

> The value for this property is nil if any of the following apply:
>
> The device is in Airplane mode. There is no SIM card in the device.
>   The device is outside of cellular service range.

Bet it's empty also in simulator.

Anyway, you should be checking **mobileNetworkCode**, since names are rarely correct (at least in Europe, where operators come and go changing their names quite often).

Answer (score 1):

by this, you can get mobile Network code, mobile country code . from these values 
you can specify which sim name is this.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo* info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier* carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;
NSString *mobileCountryCode = carrier.mobileCountryCode;
NSString *carrierName = carrier.carrierName;
NSString *isoCountryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
NSString *mobileNetworkCode = carrier.mobileNetworkCode;
```

and you can make web service for this to specify which carrier name of the network, this parameter belongs to.
these parameters can be uniquely identified from this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code).

for example, my country code is "410", my carrier network is "06" and it correctly identifies my carrier name.

I was also stuck at the same issue and now solved