# Unable to get carrier network name IOS

Tags: ios, core-telephony

i am trying to detect sim name . i had tried this code but its not working.
[image]

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"simname = %@",    [[CTCarrier alloc]carrierName]);

    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo* info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier* carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;
    NSString *mobileCountryCode = carrier.mobileCountryCode;
    NSString *carrierName = carrier.carrierName;
    NSString *isoCountryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
    NSString *mobileNetworkCode = carrier.mobileNetworkCode;

    NSLog(@"simname %@",carrierName);

    isPresented = YES;
    SelectedClub = -1;



}
```

**OUTPUT shows**

```
2014-05-17 12:54:31.574 xxxx[4302:60b] simname = (null)
2014-05-17 12:54:31.583 xxxx[4302:60b] simname Carrier
```

more over i want to know is it allowed by apple  to get sim name .

Comment: Looks like this has already been mentioned. See please this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186307/getting-wrong-carrier-name-in-ios

Comment: @AlexPeda Thnx i had solved my problem with an anwser similar to this.